# How can i print multidimensional array like this in php?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
$matrix = array(
            array(3,2,1,2,1),
            array(1,1,1,1,1),
            array(3,2,1,3,4),
            array(4,2,1,2,3),
            array(4,1,3,5,6)
        );
```

i have a multidimensional array like above, and i want to print it using foreach so i can insert it on HTML table.

How can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To insert on table, you'll have to cycle through each row of the matrix, print opening and closing table row tags and then cycle through each element of said row, printing opening and closing td tags and the element itself within the tags.

```
echo "<table>";
    foreach($matrix as $row) {
        echo "<tr>";
        foreach($row as $element) {
            echo "<td>" . $element . "</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>";
    }
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: OP never said he wants to print the data into a table!

Comment: @Rizier123 I assume he did when he said "i have a multidimensional array like above, and i want to print it using foreach so i can insert it **on table**"

Comment: brother @Laplace with full respect, i think his/she mean is database table.

Comment: @Nucleo1985 Had he meant a database table, wouldn't the tag for database or related words be added to the question?

Comment: @Laplace i take the words insert as action for database. But yes its not clear.

Answer (score 0):

Here my man, special for you:

```
foreach ($matrix as $k => $v)
{
    $sum =  count($v);
    for($i = 0; $i < $sum; $i++)
    {
        echo $v[$i] . ',';
    }
}
```

result `3,2,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,3,2,1,3,4,4,2,1,2,3,4,1,3,5,6,`

Comment: Why do you use a foreach and a for loop? That doesn't makes any sense

Comment: Provide your own answer bro!

Answer (score 0):

Try simply this way to make your multidimensional array to flat array and insert in your table(i didn't provide next part because i am not sure what kind of table **DB table or HTML table**)

```
$matrix = array(
array(3,2,1,2,1),
array(1,1,1,1,1),
array(3,2,1,3,4),
array(4,2,1,2,3),
array(4,1,3,5,6)
);
$result = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $matrix);
print '<pre>';
print_r($result);
print '</pre>';
```